# align image/icon in navbar

Tags: html, css

i am currently working with a school task by making a webpage, but i can't seem to figure out how to align an image/icon with the other buttons in the navbar. I have tried to finsd the answer, but i can't seem to find the answer after several google search. Also, i am limited to html and css only and not allowed to use tools like bootstrap.
my code for this page is below:

[image: the issue and what i want to achieve in pictures]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zero hunger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><img class="nav-img" src="images/2-zero-hunger.png"></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="game.html">Game</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

/*Navbar*/
nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D09E37;
}
nav ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;

}
nav ul li.nav-button{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
nav ul li.nav-button:hover{
  background-color: #bf8000;
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  line-height: 54px;
}
.nav-img{
  height: 58px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked my edits in css. I advise you to use the `flex` rules.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

/*Navbar*/
nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D09E37;
  
  display: flex; /*add*/
  justify-content: center; /*add*/
  align-items: center; /*add*/
}
nav ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;

}
nav ul li.nav-button{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
nav ul li.nav-button:hover{
  background-color: #bf8000;
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  line-height: 54px;
}
.nav-img{
  height: 58px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/ /*remove*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zero hunger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><img class="nav-img" src="images/2-zero-hunger.png"></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="game.html">Game</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `display: flex` on the `ul` and then set the `align-items: center` on it. The `ul` may span 100% wide according to `nav` which is its parent element. You can set the background-color on the nav. You can also add some gap around each `li` elements to make it sit nicer.

Something like this ...

```css
nav {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100vw;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope you can get some idea and adapt it to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning on the image like this

```
.nav-img{ position: absolute; 
          top: 0;
          left: 34rem; }
```

and set the ul to position:relative;

```
nav ul { 
         position: relative;
       }
```

Just add the above code and keep the previous one intact. Try changing the values of top and left as per your need.

Comment: that would work, but not if the window is being resized where the picture will overlap the navbar buttons. The issue has been solved now, but thanks for the effort!

Comment: Didnt know about it being responsive as well, thanks for the update. @VinFurr